# c++ default move assignment cannot access protected base member

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm having a piece of code that compiles with msvc having language extensions enabled, but not with language extensions disabled. It breaks down to this minimal example:

```
class A
{
    protected:
    A(const A&);
    A& operator=(const A&);
    A(A&&);
    A& operator=(A&&);
};
class B : public A
{
    public:
    B& operator=(B&&);
};
inline B& B::operator=(B&&) = default; // error C2248
```

With the error message being

> C2248 'A::A': cannot access protected member declared in class 'A'

in line 14 where the move assignment operator is defined. Interestingly, the following code compiles just fine:

```
class A
{
    protected:
    A(const A&);
    A& operator=(const A&);
    A(A&&);
    A& operator=(A&&);
};
class B : public A
{
    public:
    B& operator=(B&&) = default;
};
```

Also interestingly, this only happens with the move-assignment-operator. The copy-assignment-operator, as well as the copy- and move-constructor (but not the move-assignment-operator) of B can be defined outside the class definition, inline, and default and the code will compile.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which C++ version are you using? With VS 2017 and C++17 this compiles fine.

Comment: GCC and Clang compile this too. I could see this being an old bug in VS 2015

Comment: Can not reproduce the compiling error in VisualStudio 2015 with Update 3

Comment: @Timo I'm using Visual Studio Professional Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 and compiling for C++14. I'm unsure if my visual studio version also tells you the version of the underlying compiler. Did you remember to disable language extensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Nothing.

An explicitly defaulted definition would be exactly the same one a compiler would produce. In this case, it would move assign all bases and members. That requires the move assignment operators of those bases and members to be accessible to the one your are defaulting, of course. And yours is accessible, on account of being protected.

This is a MSVC++ bug. Try updating to a later version if you can.